# Owl carousel 2.2 with custom dots

Tags: html, css, owl-carousel-2

I have created custom dots for Owl Carousel 2.2, but I can't get them to be clickable.

Here is the code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<script>
$('#owl-offres').owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    nav: false,
    dots: false,
    dotsData:true,
    dotsContainer: '.owl-offres-dots',
});
</script>

<div id="owl-offres" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item">
        <img src="images/offre1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="images/offre2.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="images/offre3.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="images/offre4.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="images/offre5.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="owl-offres-dots">
    <button role="button" class="owl-dot"><span></span></button>
    <button role="button" class="owl-dot"><span></span></button>
    <button role="button" class="owl-dot"><span></span></button>
    <button role="button" class="owl-dot"><span></span></button>
    <button role="button" class="owl-dot"><span></span></button>
</div>
```

Here is my css:

```
.owl-offres-dots button.owl-dot.active span, 
.owl-offres-dots button.owl-dot:hover span {
  background-color: #FEAE00;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left:1px;
}
.owl-offres-dots button.owl-dot{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background: white;
   border-radius: 50%;
   height: 16px;
   width: 16px;
   position: relative;
}
```

The carousel on autoplay functions well, but dots are not clickable and they don't show the active state.

Any idea why? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$('#owl-offres').owlCarousel({
    ......
    dots: true,
    .......
});
</script>
```